# In possession or in the possession

Tags: semantics

Do you agree with this interpretation?

Jack was found in possession of drugs. (He had drugs)

Jack was found in the possession of drugs. (He was obsessed with drugs. Or even, drugs had him.)

Answer (score 1):

No.  I'd understand both to be equivalent. The form with "the" is particularly common in the full expression "found in the possession...":

> Any student found to be in the possession of drugs or using or distributing illegal and controlled substances can lead directly to disciplinary procedures  (From Sussex University Health and Wellbeing policy)

> If you are found in the possession of drugs you will be reported for the offence. (Northumbria Police)

However

> If the police stop you and you are in possession of drugs, it is likely that you will be arrested.  (Northern Ireland government information)

As you see, both phrases are used in the same way.

My strategy for researching these question was simply to search for "in the possession of drugs" in Google, and look at the example sentences, taking note of the quality of the source (a UK university, police or government website is a high-quality source, a private blog or a source from a country where English is not the main language would be a lower quality source.)